# C#/Moq - How to fill with multi-level test data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I'm new to Moq, and I'd like to write unit tests using it. I have a database with a few tables, like:

```
EducationUser   | Application
- UsrName         - Student
- UsrPwd          - CourseId
- UsrChallenge    - Date
- IsTeacher       - Grade
- FullName
```

This is a database on a `localdb`, which I want to mock. I've created the entities using the Entity Framework. The interface of these entities is `IEducationEntities`.

Now I'd like to create a mock object and do some testing of some Web Services, like:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void LoginTest()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(_accountController.Login("andrew", "DefaultPassword"));
        Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode, "User unable to log in with correct login info");

    }
```

For this, from what I've understood from the [documentation](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#properties), I should be able to do something like:

```
[TestClass()]
public class AccountControllerTests : ApiController
{
    Mock<IEducationEntities> _entities = new Mock<IEducationEntities>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    private AccountController _accountController;

public AccountControllerTests() {
        _accountController = new AccountController(_entities.Object);
        _entities.Setup(table => table.EducationUsers.UsrName).Returns("andrew");
        _entities.Setup(table => table.EducationUsers.UsrPwd).Returns("DefaultPassword");
}
[TestMethod] //etc, defining tests below
```

However, this doesn't work at all, since the entities generated from the databse do not contain information about subfields apparently, and I get the error:

> 'DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'UsrPwd' and
>   no extension method 'UsrPwd' accepting a first argument of type
>   'DbSet' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I missing? How to fill a `moq` object with test data that has the same structure as my database?

Comment: In your example table structure, the password field is called `UsrPassword`, but you call it `UsrPwd` in your test/mock code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article describes how to mock your Entity Framework context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx) (assuming you're using version 6 or later)

You'll do something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomething()    
{
   // Create the user data
   var educationUsers = new List<EducationUser>
   {
       new EducationUser
       {
           UsrName = "andrew",
           UsrPwd = "DefaultPassword"
       }
   }.AsQueryable();

   // Create the DbSet that contains the user data and wire it up to return the user data that was created above
   Mock<DbSet<EducationUser>> educationUsersDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<EducationUser>>();
   educationUsersDbSet.As<IQueryable<EducationUser>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(educationUsers.Provider);
   educationUsersDbSet.As<IQueryable<EducationUser>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(educationUsers.Expression);
   educationUsersDbSet.As<IQueryable<EducationUser>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(educationUsers.ElementType);
   educationUsersDbSet.As<IQueryable<EducationUser>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(educationUsers.GetEnumerator());

   // Create the mock context and wire up its EducationUsers property to return the DbSet that was created above
   var context = new Mock<IEducationEntities>();
   context.Setup(e => e.EducationUsers).Returns(educationUsersDbSet.Object);

   // Create the account controller using the mock DbContext
   _accountController = new AccountController(context.Object);

   // ... the rest of your testing code ...
}
```

It'll probably get annoying to configure the mock `DbSet` for every entity type for all of your unit tests, so you could make a method to do it.

```
public static Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> CreateMockDbSet<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> models) where TEntity : class
{
    Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<TEntity>>();

    dbSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(e => e.ElementType).Returns(models.ElementType);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(e => e.Expression).Returns(models.Expression);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(e => e.GetEnumerator()).Returns(models.GetEnumerator());
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(e => e.Provider).Returns(models.Provider);

    return dbSet;
}
```

Then your test method becomes

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomething()    
{
   // Create the user data
   var educationUsers = new List<EducationUser>
   {
       new EducationUser
       {
           UsrName = "andrew",
           UsrPwd = "DefaultPassword"
       }
   }.AsQueryable();

   // Create the DbSet that contains the user data and wire it up to return the user data that was created above
   Mock<DbSet<EducationUser>> educationUsersDbSet = new CreateMockDbSet(educationUsers);

   // Create the mock context and wire up its EducationUsers property to return the DbSet that was created above
   var context = new Mock<IEducationEntities>();
   context.Setup(e => e.EducationUsers).Returns(educationUsersDbSet.Object);

   // Create the account controller using the mock DbContext
   _accountController = new AccountController(context.Object);

   // ... the rest of your testing code ...
}
```

Comment: The above used to be the approach I would take as well, until I started implementing the async/await pattern. If you read the provided link it explains this approach doesn't work for that. Also, the approach they provide for async/await doesn't work with EF Core, so be aware. I use EF Core's UseInMemoryDatabase now for unit testing down to the repository layer with much success. If you are interested in an example I'll provide one.

Comment: Yes, I'd love to see an example.